# Selenium webdriver javaexecutor with for loop

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

Hi I am new to the selenium webdriver so i don't know how to use for loop while using javascript executor so can anyone convert this below code into for loop or any loop, in below code as you can observe just div[] is changing which is after div[6] in this line driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='unfreezedGridBody']/div[6]/**div[5]**/div/div/span[3]"));

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

```
int count = 
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@id='unfreezedGridBody']/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/span[3]")).size();
System.out.println(count);

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
WebElement dropdowns = 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='unfreezedGridBody']/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/span[3]"));
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", dropdowns);
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", dropdowns);
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-content='PASS']")).click();
Thread.sleep(10000);



JavascriptExecutor jse2 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement dropdowns2 = 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='unfreezedGridBody']/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/span[3]"));
jse2.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", dropdowns2);
jse2.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", dropdowns2);
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-content='PASS']")).click();
Thread.sleep(10000);


JavascriptExecutor jse3 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement dropdowns3 = 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='unfreezedGridBody']/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/span[3]"));
jse3.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", dropdowns3);
jse3.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", dropdowns3);
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-content='PASS']")).click();
Thread.sleep(10000);


JavascriptExecutor jse4 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement dropdowns4 = 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='unfreezedGridBody']/div[6]/div[4]/div/div/span[3]"));

JavascriptExecutor jse5 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement dropdowns5 = 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='unfreezedGridBody']/div[6]/div[5]/div/div/span[3]"));
jse5.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", dropdowns5);``
jse5.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", dropdowns5);
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-content='PASS']")).click();
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Comment: Can you share html code or url? As solution for this is to change the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you

```
    String xpath = "//[@id='unfreezedGridBody']/div[6]/div[%d]/div/div/span[3]";
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    for(int i=1; i<4; i++){
        WebElement dropdowns = driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(xpath,i)));
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", dropdowns);
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", dropdowns);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-content='PASS']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
```